# Cocos2d DrawPoints

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new in OpenGLES, and tring to draw a points, but no results, here is my draw method

```
-(void) draw
{
    [super draw];
    if(!isBackgroundInited)
    {
         glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_POINTS);
        ccDrawColor4B(100,100,100,255);
        ccPointSize(2);
        [self drawDots];
        isBackgroundInited=YES;
        glDisable(GL_POINTS);
         glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

}

-(void) drawDots
{

    CGSize activeArea=CGSizeMake(winSize.width-2*margin, winSize.height-2*margin);
    float xMargin=activeArea.width/dotsCount;
    float yMargin=activeArea.height/dotsCount;
    float yPosition=margin;
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
    {
        float xPosition=margin;
        for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            ccDrawPoint(CGPointMake(xPosition, yPosition));
            xPosition+=xMargin;
        }
        yPosition+=yMargin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're drawing the dots only on the very first frame. Remove the `isBackgroundInited` ivar and things should appear on your screen.

OpenGL clears the framebuffer every frame, as is customary for games, so the entire contents of the screen need to be redrawn every frame.

Comment: is there any technique speed up the process or to prevent the behavior? or push the frame to frame buffer and use it for further frames?

Comment: You can render this to a render texture and from then on use the texture. Though then that texture will be rendered to the framebuffer every frame. The difference in performance, if any, will be marginal.